# Strange result of UPDATE..WHERE..EXISTS with ORA_ROWSCN as join condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a quick demo to show the case:

### 1. Create table

```sql
DROP TABLE ora_rowscn_test CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE ora_rowscn_test(
    row_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    row_value NUMBER NOT NULL
)
ROWDEPENDENCIES;
```

Note that the table is created with `ROWDEPENDENCIES` flag, so two rows in same block can have different ROWSCN.

### 2. Prepare data

```sql
BEGIN
    delete ORA_ROWSCN_TEST;
    
    INSERT INTO ORA_ROWSCN_TEST (ROW_ID,ROW_VALUE) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
    commit;
    INSERT INTO ORA_ROWSCN_TEST (ROW_ID,ROW_VALUE) VALUES ( 2, 2 );
--    commit;
    INSERT INTO ORA_ROWSCN_TEST (ROW_ID,ROW_VALUE) VALUES ( 3, 3 );
    commit;
END;
/
```

Note that commit matters here. If multiple rows are updated in one transaction, they will get same ORA_ROWSCN, otherwise, ORA_ROWSCNs will be different.
This behavior seems correct according to Oracle Doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm, .

`It is not absolutely precise, because Oracle tracks SCNs by transaction committed for the block in which the row resides.`

### 3. Check ORA_ROWSCN of rows

```sql
/*******************************************************************************
Since we updated row 1 and 2 in two seperate transactions, their ORA_ROWSCN is different, 
but row 2 and row 3 share same ORA_ROWSCN.

1116438854 1 1
1116438857 2 2
1116438857 3 3
*******************************************************************************/
select ort.ora_rowscn, ort.* from ora_rowscn_test ort;
```

### 4. Update values

```sql
DECLARE
    lv_number_of_rows      integer;
    lv_test_method         integer := 1;  -- 1:exists, 2:merge, 3:in
    lv_first_rowscn        number := 1116438854;  -- SCN of row 1
    lv_second_rowscn       number := 1116438857;  -- SCN of row 2
    
BEGIN

    if lv_test_method = 1 then

        UPDATE ora_rowscn_test ort
           SET ROW_VALUE = dbms_random.random
         WHERE EXISTS (
                 SELECT 1
                   FROM (
                          SELECT 1 row_id, lv_first_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual 
                           UNION ALL
                          SELECT 2 row_id, lv_second_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
                        ) tmp
                  WHERE ort.row_id = tmp.row_id
                    AND ort.ora_rowscn = tmp.last_ora_rowscn
               );
        
    elsif lv_test_method = 2 then
    
        MERGE INTO ora_rowscn_test ort
        USING ( SELECT 1 row_id, lv_first_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 row_id, lv_second_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
              )
        tmp ON ( tmp.last_ora_rowscn = ort.ora_rowscn
           AND tmp.row_id = ort.row_id )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
           SET ROW_VALUE = dbms_random.random;
           
    elsif lv_test_method = 3 then
    
        UPDATE ora_rowscn_test ort
           SET ROW_VALUE = dbms_random.random
         WHERE ( ort.row_id, ort.ora_rowscn ) IN (
                  SELECT 1 row_id, lv_first_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 row_id, lv_second_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
                );
           
    end if;

    lv_number_of_rows := sql%rowcount;
    dbms_output.put_line('lv_number_of_rows: ' || lv_number_of_rows);
    dbms_output.put_line(case when lv_number_of_rows = 2 then 'SUCCESS' else 'FAILURE' end);
    
    rollback; -- rollback for repeatedly testing
--    commit; -- commit to check result
    
END;
/
```

Here I tried 3 methods to update rows and they are supposed to be equivalent to each other, at least I thought it is. But UPDATE..WHERE..EXISTS failed when multiple unequal SCNs are joined (e.g. 1116438854 and 1116438857 are joined simultaneously), whereas MERGE and UPDATE..WHERE..IN succeed in both cases.

| Cases | UDPATE..WHERE..EXISTS | MERGE | UPDATE..WHERE..IN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Same SCNs | success | success | success |
| Diff SCNs | *fail* | success | success |

So my question is what makes the difference, exist clause, ORA_ROWSCN or combined?

Comment: if I understood your predicament, you think the first update does not work as you expect, because it does not update the 2 rows with same `ora_rowscn` ? I am asking because the method 1 is not the same as the others ( 2 and 3 )

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I'm using both row_id and rowscn as join condition, so I expect no matter SCNs are unique or not, it should update 2 rows as I specified row_id 1 and 2. But when SCN are same, it updated 2 rows; not same, it update only 1 row, that's wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `exists` does not work as you think in the first method.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE ora_rowscn_test CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE ora_rowscn_test(
    row_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    row_value NUMBER NOT NULL
)
ROWDEPENDENCIES;

Table created.

SQL> BEGIN
  2      delete ORA_ROWSCN_TEST;
  3      INSERT INTO ORA_ROWSCN_TEST (ROW_ID,ROW_VALUE) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
  4      commit;
  5      INSERT INTO ORA_ROWSCN_TEST (ROW_ID,ROW_VALUE) VALUES ( 2, 2 );
  6  --    commit;
  7      INSERT INTO ORA_ROWSCN_TEST (ROW_ID,ROW_VALUE) VALUES ( 3, 3 );
  8      commit;
  9* END;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.



 SQL> select ort.ora_rowscn, ort.* from ora_rowscn_test ort;

          ORA_ROWSCN     ROW_ID  ROW_VALUE
-------------------- ---------- ----------
      13142311025954          1          1
      13142311025956          2          2
      13142311025956          3          3
```

The reason why your first update does not work in the way you think it should, it is because you are using `EXISTS`

> The Exists keyword evaluates true or false, but the IN keyword will
> compare all values in the corresponding subuery column.  If you are
> using the IN operator, the SQL engine will scan all records fetched
> from the inner query. **On the other hand, if we are using EXISTS, the
> SQL engine will stop the scanning process as soon as it found a match.**

That is why your update ends with one row. Both methods, 2 and 3 use in operators which are evaluating the whole inner query. The method 1 will not update all records concerning the EXIST condition, even if you use the whole data set.

**Demo**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      lv_number_of_rows      integer;
  3      lv_test_method         integer := 1;
  4      lv_first_rowscn        number  := 13142311025954;  -- SCN of row 1
  5      lv_second_rowscn       number  := 13142311025956;  -- SCN of row 2
  6  BEGIN
  7      if lv_test_method = 1
  8     then
  9          UPDATE ora_rowscn_test ort
 10             SET ROW_VALUE = dbms_random.random
 11           WHERE EXISTS (
 12                   SELECT 1
 13                     FROM (
 14                            SELECT 1 row_id, lv_first_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
 15                             UNION ALL
 16                            SELECT 2 row_id, lv_second_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
 17                                                UNION ALL
 18                                               SELECT 3 row_id, lv_second_rowscn last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
 19                          ) tmp
 20                    WHERE ort.row_id = tmp.row_id
 21                      AND ort.ora_rowscn = tmp.last_ora_rowscn
 22                 );
 23     end if;
 24      lv_number_of_rows := sql%rowcount;
 25      dbms_output.put_line('lv_number_of_rows: ' || lv_number_of_rows);
 26      dbms_output.put_line(case when lv_number_of_rows = 2 then 'SUCCESS' else 'FAILURE' end);
 27      rollback; -- rollback for repeatedly testing
 28  --    commit; -- commit to check result
 29* END;
SQL> /
lv_number_of_rows: 2
SUCCESS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**UPDATE**

Let's deep down in the update of the method 1.

```
SQL> select ort.ora_rowscn, ort.* from ora_rowscn_test ort

        ORA_ROWSCN     ROW_ID  ROW_VALUE
------------------ ---------- ----------
    13142311051553          1          1
    13142311051555          2          2
    13142311051555          3          3

SQL> UPDATE ora_rowscn_test ort
  2             SET ROW_VALUE = dbms_random.random
  3           WHERE EXISTS (
  4                   SELECT 1
  5                     FROM (
  6                            SELECT 1 row_id, 13142311051553 last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
  7                             UNION ALL
  8                            SELECT 2 row_id, 13142311051555 last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
  9                                                UNION ALL
 10                                               SELECT 3 row_id, 13142311051555 last_ora_rowscn FROM dual
 11                          ) tmp
 12                    WHERE ort.row_id = tmp.row_id
 13*                     AND ort.ora_rowscn = tmp.last_ora_rowscn )
SQL> /

2 rows updated.

SQL> select ora_rowscn , ort.* from ora_rowscn_test ort ;

        ORA_ROWSCN     ROW_ID  ROW_VALUE
------------------ ---------- ----------
    13142311051553          1          1
                            2  552186282
                            3 1778577911
```

What happens here:

- The `select 1` with the where condition only affects the first iteration of the exists condition
- As soon as the exists find a match, it ends
- That is why you get two rows updated.

If you run instead any variation ( methods 2, 3 ) or the one below, you will see how it works.

```
SQL> UPDATE ora_rowscn_test ort
           SET ROW_VALUE = 
           ( with x as 
           ( SELECT 1 row_id, 13142311051553 last_ora_rowscn, 1 row_value FROM dual 
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 row_id, 13142311051555 last_ora_rowscn, 2 row_value FROM dual
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT 3 row_id, 13142311051555 last_ora_rowscn, 3 row_value FROM dual
           ) select dbms_random.value from x where ort.row_id = x.row_id and ort.ora_rowscn = x.last_ora_rowscn
             and ort.row_value = x.row_value 
           )
           ;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select ora_rowscn , ort.* from ora_rowscn_test ort ;

        ORA_ROWSCN     ROW_ID  ROW_VALUE
------------------ ---------- ----------
                            1 .017441695
                            2 .802508693
                            3 .912092903
```

**However, having said that, the only way to use `exists` in the way you want it, is to use it inside a join with the parent table.**

```
SQL> UPDATE ora_rowscn_test ort SET ROW_VALUE = dbms_random.random
WHERE EXISTS ( select 1 from 
                   (
                      SELECT 1 row_id, 13142311051553 last_ora_rowscn, 1 row_value FROM dual
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT 2 row_id, 13142311051555 last_ora_rowscn, 2 row_value FROM dual
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT 3 row_id, 13142311051555 last_ora_rowscn, 3 row_value FROM dual
                    ) tmp
                       join ( select ora_rowscn , ort.* from ora_rowscn_test ort ) ort 
                       on  ort.row_id = tmp.row_id
                       AND ort.ora_rowscn = tmp.last_ora_rowscn 
                       AND ort.row_value = tmp.row_value 
                   );

3 rows updated.

SQL> select ora_rowscn , ort.* from ora_rowscn_test ort ;

        ORA_ROWSCN     ROW_ID  ROW_VALUE
------------------ ---------- ----------
                            1 1175024608
                            2 -2.147E+09
                            3 -1.361E+09
```

Comment: The doc explaination, and I quote, "On the other hand, if we are using EXISTS, the SQL engine will stop the scanning process as soon as it found a match." can't explain why it works fine for unique SCN joins I think. It do update 2 rows when join with (12345, 1) and (12345, 2), row_ids are different, engine do not stop, right? Maybe I don't understand "stop" in correct way? BTW, in your code, "case when lv_number_of_rows = 2 then", 2 should be 3 cause you're giving 3 rows and it should update 3 rows, that's a "success"

Comment: @Joshz, of course it should be 2. I did not explain it right. I updated the post

Comment: The `exists` stops means that it does not evaluate the whole data in the inner query. As I understood for the documentation, it means that the processing of the inner query will stop.

Comment: Your inner query is (13142311025954, 1), (13142311025956, 2), (13142311025956, 3), but you say it should update 2 rows, could you explain in detail how that will happen?

Comment: @Joshz, I update the answer with more details.

Comment: my original intention was to only update row 1 and row 2, NOT including row 3, so a successful update will only update 2 rows. In your 2 new examples, it seems they're both updating whole data set. You can comment out hardcoded row 3 and run again, first update-with dml will raise NULL constriant error because joining row 3 returns null, second update-exists dml will still update 3 rows, I think it's because exists always evals as true given any success join in this subquery (if no successful join exists, it will update 0 rows). Correct me if I'm wrong and thank you anyway!

Comment: @Joshz, a nice way to say thank you is to upvote the answer. anyway, so your intention is to update only rows 1 and 2 ( row_id = 1 and row_id = 2 ) . Am I right ?

Comment: Right. Im not quite a frequent user of SO, thanks for reminding, let's wait and see.